# Qt: moc Error 1: variable ' ' has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new to Qt and Qml. For practicing QML Extensions with C++ , I built a qt project and hand-coded following the codes on ( https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html# ), but I received two error messages of type: "moc Error 1: variable  '   ' has initializer but incomplete type", one for 'QPen pen' and another for 'painter' in the code below.
 
I added `#included <QPainter>` in "piechart.h" and the code compiles and runs as expected. However, I also opened the actual tutorial code, which I had downloaded and installed along with Qt 5.13, and the code compiles and runs without `#included <QPainter>`. Could you explain to me the reason for this discrepancy?! 
PS: I noticed that "PieChart.pro" differs between the two projects although both are based on qmake, but I am not sure 1)whether this is the root of evil; 2) why these files differ when I followed Qt Creator project wizard. Also linux command line `diff` between the two "moc_predefs.h" shows there are some differences between the two projects.

```c
void PieChart::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    QPen pen(m_color, 2);
    painter->setPen(pen);
    painter->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    painter->drawPie(boundingRect().adjusted(1, 1, -1, -1), 90 * 16, 290 * 16);

}
```

Comment: The common C++ question that doesn't relate to Qt. To use some class you have to include its declaration. In your case to use `QPen` you have to include its declaration from the file `#include <QPen>`. Some another .h file can already include it, in your case `QPainter` so you can only add `#include <QPainter>` (not #includeD!!!). There is no another way. If you miss the declaration you will get something like _incomplete type_ error since a compiler has no info what this type is.

Comment: @folibis: one could assume that <QPainter> header could have been included in <QQuickPaintedItem>. As I explained in the answer, the source of my confusion was the poor writing of the tutorial. Also, I was unable to correct #included. But thanks for commenting, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I checked closely the actual tutorial code on my hard disk. `<QPainter>` was in fact included in "piechart.cpp", whereas I was looking for it in "piechart.h", where `QPainter` object is passed as an argument to `paint` function. In fact I included ` in the header file. On the website, it does not mention it in the cpp file unfortunately, which was the cause of my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

this problem did happen always when you become lazy to import the header file of that class  , and when you do it will kill the error . so try to add this  : `#include <QPainter>`